# PineScript - Miltiple Entry/Exit arguments

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, pine-script-v4

I want to create multiple strategy.entry and exit arguments. But when I run the script, the other arguments will not activate because the previous line of entry argument is still in the trade and hasn't closed/exited yet.
Do I have to define the total position size and specify it for each argument? if yes, can you explain it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have multiple entry/exits in the same direction, it is called `pyramiding`. By default it is set to zero. You need to either do it programmatically or manually change it.

> ***pyramiding (const int)*** The maximum number of entries allowed in the
> same direction. If the value is 0, only one entry order in the same
> direction can be opened, and additional entry orders are rejected. The
> default value is 0.

```
strategy(title="MyStrategy", shorttitle="MS", pyramiding = 10)
```

[Here](https://kodify.net/tradingview/strategy-settings/strategy-pyramiding/) is an old (v2) but good source on this matter.

Comment: and since I am new to pine script I don't know what is the proper way to address multiple entries. Should I just make a different "strategy.entry", or there is a more professional way of doing it?

Comment: You don't need to do anything specific. If your buy condition becomes `true` while you are already long, it will just place another buy order. If you want to use different conditions for different entries, then you need to call additional `strategy.entry()` functions with different `when` conditions.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the help!